# "I'll go buy some tomatoes." and "I go buy some tomatoes." Which one makes more sense?

Tags: present-tense, subjunctives, future-tense

"**I'll go buy some tomatoes.**" and "**I go buy some tomatoes.**" Which one makes more sense?

I think "**I'll go buy some tomatoes.**" makes more sense since the simple future in this case shows a voluntary action.

Whereas the simple present shows the habit, fact, or generalization.

So, "**I go buy some tomatoes.**"  doesn't seem to be a common sentence.

Comment: You might want to add two other options: "I'm going to buy some tomatoes." and "I go to buy some tomatoes.".  The answers might help you understand quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I go buy some tomatoes.

shows the action is habitual

> I go buy *(some)* tomatoes on Mondays.

However, if you are saying you will do it in the future

> I'll go buy some tomatoes.
>   I'm going to buy some tomatoes.

are appropriate.

Comment: You put "some" in parenthesis, but the statement might be misinterpreted without the "some" as "I go by tomatoes". (At least that's what it sounds like to my ears; could be subjective.)

Comment: @MrLister The statement *I go buy some tomatoes on Mondays* could be misheard as *I go by some tomatoes on Mondays*, so I don't think saying or not saying *some* here has anything to do with increasing or decreasing the likelihood of "misinterpretation."

Answer (score 1):

"I'll go buy some tomatoes" sounds natural to my (American) ear as a statement of what I plan to do in the future.  Unless otherwise noted, it usually refers to the near future.

"I go buy some tomatoes" sounds natural to my (American) ear as a hypothetical.  For example:

> "Suppose I go buy some tomatoes, and they all have worms.  What should I do?"
>
> Suppose my friends and I are playing *Dungeons and Dragons*.  (*Dungeons and Dragons* is a game where people pretend to be a team of adventurers.)  The Dungeon Master asks me what I want to do next.  I tell him, "I go buy some tomatoes."

In all of these examples, the word "go" is optional.  The word "go" helps imply that the proposed action is in the near future.

Comment: I always though, after go we should use to+infinitive. Sounds interesting